# 1TB harddrive not working in linux

Tags: linux, filesystems, hard-drive, partition

Hai

I  bought a 1 TB new hard disk. When installed in linux it say's fsck.ext3 file system not found. when i checked the BIOS it detected the hard disk. what to do to solve the problem in linux?.

Thank you

Comment: Just to make things clear, this is a newly bought hard disk, on which noone has created any partitions or file systems?

Comment: No file system was created

Comment: I think you need to provide a little more information on exactly what you are doing. What commands are you running, what does your /etc/fstab look like etc.

Answer (score 5):

If you say 'no filesystem was created', I suggest you use fdisk to create partition(s) and the mke2fs or a similar utility to create a filesystem. Filesystems do not magically appear; you need to create them.

More specifically, you run

```
fdisk -l
```

to check whether the disk is detected by the OS at all. Then you run

```
fdisk /dev/yourdisk
```

and create partition(s) with the appropriate commands. fdisk has a fine help function, but basically, you create a new partition with 'n', and fdisk will ask you for more information.

Then, you might have to run

```
partprobe /dev/yourdisk
```

to make sure Linux sees your new partition(s) correctly.

Then, at last, you run

```
mke2fs -j /dev/yourparition
```

on each created partition to create ext3 filesystems. For ext2, leave off the -j. But you can also use any mkfs.* utility available on your system.

Finally, add the new partition(s) to your /etc/fstab file, by adding (a) line(s) following this convention:

```
device     mountpoint   filesystem     filesystemoptions     fs_freq     fs_passno
```

So, for example:

```
/dev/sda1     /u01     ext2     defaults     1     2
```

and you're all done.

Comment: Shouldn't the last number be 2 on the fstab entry? As I understand it, it's rather important that the pass number is higher than the one set for root.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Missed that. +1 for you and edited my post.

Comment: Also, suggesting something else than ext2 for a modern 1TB harddrive might make better use of that disk. Perhaps XFS or something similar :)

Comment: ...and he probably does NOT want it mounted in boot.  A safer example might be /export/disk2

Comment: @pauska: I am not suggesting ext2, I am suggesting ext3, which makes perfect sense to me, as it is the default on virtually all distros today. I am merely telling what the -j option does. 
@David Mackintosh: the /etc/fstab snippet is an example, I am certainly not suggesting mounting a 1TB drive at boot. Where he wants it mounted is his thing to decide on.

Comment: ext3 is terribly inefficient for large partitions.  XFS or ext4 are usually the recommended file systems unless you're running something mission critical that values ultra-stability over anything else.

Comment: In case someone visits this as a resource, an update: you should use flags -cu with fdisk:  fdisk -cu /dev/sda to ensure partition table compatibility with advanced disk format common to drivers manufactured in 2011 and later having 4K sector sizes.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you need to use a utility like [Gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) to create a partition, then use the appropriate utility for the filesystem you want to create the FS.

Comment: Answering too quickly.

Comment: +1 for the user friendly GParted as opposed to a bunch of commandline executions.  GParted can also be used to format to the partition you want.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a filesystem with mkfs on the disk before using it. You may want to partition it first too. Partitions aren't mandatory to linux if you simply want to use it as a data disk, however you'll need to partition it to be able to boot from it.