# 1TB hard disk not working in linux

Tags: linux, hard-drive, fsck

I installed a new 1TB internal hard disk in my linux machine after creating ext3 file system. But while booting it asks for the root password then it say's file system ext3.fsck not found.  If i detach the 1TB hard disk the system boots normally. How to solve this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Check the appropriate line in your /etc/fstab.  Does it look like

```
/dev/sdXX   /<mount point>    ext3   defaults    0  0
```

Your values will definitely differ, the one we're concerned about here is the "ext3".

Comment: If this would be the problem, disconnecting it would not fix it. A drive that is set for automatic mount during boot that is missing will trigger an emergency root shell too, just like a disk with a wrong filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

Though this question is *very* related (if not the same) to the one you asked here: [1TB harddrive not working in linux](https://serverfault.com/questions/91302/1tb-harddrive-not-working-in-linux), here's a little tidbit anyway.

What you are experiencing, is very likely Linux trying to mount your new disk instead as your root filesystem instead of your existing disk. This is why using LVM, UUID's or ext3 labels in /etc/fstab is such a good idea.

My guess is your disk is detected as /dev/sda by the kernel, so it tries to set it up as /, but is unsuccessful in that, because the disk is emtpy. To verify this, can you attach the disk to a different SATA or ATA connector (preferably as a slave) and then try again?